# How to function<void(string message)> bind to member function?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to `function<void(string message)> somePointer;`
set to member function ?
I have inside

```
class Temp {
public:
void test(string message) {}
};
```

and I tried `somePointer = &Temp::test;`
but got error. How to bind somePointer to member function of some class ?

Comment: Try something like `std::function<void(std::string message)> f = std::bind(&Temp::test, Temp{}, std::placeholders::_1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
std::function<void(std::string message)> somePointer = 
    std::bind((&Temp::test, instance_of_Temp, std::placeholders::_1);
```

You can also use a lambda:

```
std::function<void(std::string message)> somePointer = 
    [&instance_of_temp](std::string message){instance_of_temp.test(message);}
```

Comment: You still need `std::placeholders::_1` for the `message` argument.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot bind that function signature (`function<void(string)>`) to that member function. Because that member function requires an instance of the `Temp` class in order to call it. If you have a particular `Temp` instance you want to bind, you can do that. With a lambda, for example.

```
Temp x;
function<void(string)> somePointer = [&x](string message) {
    x.test(message);
};
```

You could also probably use `std::bind`, but I would just mess up the syntax, because I rarely ever see any reason to use it in the presence of lambdas.